# Can't find any software in 'Ubuntu software center'

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I actually can't find any software in Ubuntu software center. When I am typing `vlc` or `flash player` it says not found. Help me please.

Comment: Maybe there are errors when the Software Center attempts to download the lists of available packages. Please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and enter the command `sudo apt-get update`. Enter your password when you're asked for it. Then please [edit] your question and paste the output of that command. It will probably help us to trouble shoot your issue. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal , then type :`sudo apt-get update` then you can download from the software center easilly .

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt-get update` and see if that works. If not, you can still install such software through the terminal, with `sudo apt-get install PROGRAM-NAME`, PROGRAM-NAME would be vlc or some other program.